# How to modify the length of a column datatype only once sql server ce?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

I want to change a column's size from `nvarchar(1000)` to `nvarchar(2000)`. I know I have to use

```
alter table [Table] 
alter column [Column] nvarchar(2000)
```

But I want to do this only once. I want to check its actual size and make the change only once. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view to avoid doing it more than once:

```
SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Categories'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Category Name'
```